# Roi to detect eye region

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to assign ROI to detected face so that only eye region is cropped.

I tried this :

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 4, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(20, 20));

size_t i = 0; // ic is index of current element

for (i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected faces)

{

    Point pt1(faces[i].x, faces[i].y); // Display detected faces on main window - live stream from camera
    Point pt2((faces[i].x + faces[i].height), (faces[i].y + faces[i].width));
    rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);

    // set ROI for the eyes

    Rect Roi = faces[i];

    Roi.height = Roi.height / 4;

    Roi.y = Roi.y + Roi.height;

    cv::Mat crop = frame(Roi);

    imshow("ROI", crop);
```

this was the output :[ROI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGLkb.png)

How can make this output more accurate like this image
[Only eyes Roi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Vy0.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function below to shrink Rect with a given percentage value

```
Rect shrinkRect( Rect rect, int percent )
{
        if (percent>99)
        return rect;

    Rect newrect;
    newrect.width=( rect.width * percent ) / 100;
    newrect.height=( rect.height * percent ) / 100;
    newrect.x = rect.x + ( rect.width - newrect.width ) / 2;
    newrect.y = rect.y + ( rect.height - newrect.height ) / 2;

    return newrect;
}
```

test code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Rect shrinkRect( Rect rect, int percent )
{
    if (percent>99)
        return rect;

    Rect newrect;
    newrect.width=( rect.width * percent ) / 100;
    newrect.height=( rect.height * percent ) / 100;
    newrect.x = rect.x + ( rect.width - newrect.width ) / 2;
    newrect.y = rect.y + ( rect.height - newrect.height ) / 2;

    return newrect;
}

int main( void )
{

    Rect r;
    r.x = 100;
    r.y = 100;
    r.width = 200;
    r.height = 200;

    cout << r  << endl;
    cout << shrinkRect( r, 75 ) << endl;
    cout << shrinkRect( r, 50 ) << endl;
    cout << shrinkRect( r, 30 ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

test code output:

```
[200 x 200 from (100, 100)]
[150 x 150 from (125, 125)]
[100 x 100 from (150, 150)]
[60 x 60 from (170, 170)]
```

Comment: <pre> I have used your function but the output was the same nothing changed

Comment: I tried this and assigned these values :  Rect Roi = faces[i];

  Roi.height = 90;
  Roi.y = 0;
  Roi.x=0;
  Roi.width=300;
               shrinkRect( Roi, 30 );
  cv::Mat crop = frame(Roi);   it searches outside the face region

Comment: you can use like : Roi = shrinkRect( Roi, 70 );

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use eye classifiers to get the only the eyes region.

There are separate (left/right) eyes classifiers and eye pairs classifiers (e.g. haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml)

These should give you the ROI of the eyes.

Comment: I have used eyepair_big , It shows the eye region  but , my problem is that when I convert this detected eye region to ycbcr and extract Y channel  it is not displayed correctly as expected

Comment: If you now detect the eye pair as expected I think that this question is solved and I'm happy it helped you.
You should open a new question regarding the channel extraction, and attach your code.